# Scipy linkage() function returning inconsistent results

Tags: scipy, linkage, hierarchical-clustering

I have a C# program that does some analysis, prints out a full 2D matrix of distance values, and then launches a scipy python process (anaconda, fwiw) to do hierarchical clustering.  Here's the problem: I need to impose some kind of ordering on them so that they have an ordering along each axis.  My code looks more or less like this:

```
var set = set.OrderBy(x => x.GetHashCode());

foreach(Point p1 in set)
{
  foreach(Point p2 in set)
  {
    double distance = Distance(p1,p2);
    //save out the distance so that it can be written to a 2d matrix
  }
}

//write out the 2d matrix...

//call python...
```

Here's the trick: when I change the ordering scheme - maybe sort by size, or even a random number generator - python calculates different numbers of clusters for the same cutoff.  I know the distance values are the same - I print them all ordered by size to a single string and calculate an md5 hash on that string, and the hash is always the same.  I know that the linkage() function in scipy doesn't like 2d matrices (some bug I read about), but once the 2d matrix is read in, I convert it to a compressed matrix with squareform(distMatrix) as shown here: [Use Distance Matrix in scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952587/use-distance-matrix-in-scipy-cluster-hierarchy-linkage).

Anyway, any ideas?  I really have a hard time believing that scipy has the bug, but I'm running out of options...

thanks!
-denny-

Comment: What you need to provide here is a way for someone to reproduce the issue. In particular: (i) the saved matrix, (ii) the relevant parts of Python code that you use, preferably as a runnable script

Comment: I have been looking at this and I think that the problem is that hierarchical clustering may not always produce the same clusters if a distance tie exists e.g. A,B are 0.5 apart and C,D are 0.5 apart.  In that case, it has to arbitrarily choose one, at which point that may lead down a clustering path different from some other scenario.  Can anyone confirm that scipy linkage() behaves like this?  The IBM SPSS function seems to (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476880); I think it is a aspect of the algorithm not a failure of implementation.

Comment: It is indeed a bit hard to follow, e. g. after a shuffle of the input data `X`, the output of `fclusterdata` will change. Maybe, as you suggested, sorting effects the selection in case of two equal distances. ["Warning: When the minimum distance pair in the forest is chosen, there may be two or more pairs with the same minimum distance. This implementation may chose a different minimum than the MATLAB version.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html)