# Triangle vs. Square distance matrix for Hierarchical Clustering Python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have been experimenting with `Hierarchical Clustering` and in `R` it's so simple `hclust(as.dist(X),method="average")`  . I found a method in `Python` that is pretty simple as well, except I'm a little confused on what's going on with my input distance matrix.

I have a similarity matrix (`DF_c93tom` w/ a smaller test version called `DF_sim`) that I convert into a dissimilarity matrix `DF_dissm = 1 - DF_sim`.

I use this as input into `linkage` from `scipy` but the documentation says it takes in a square or triangle matrix.  I get a different cluster for inputing a `lower triangle`, `upper triangle`, and `square matrix`.  Why is this? It wants an upper triangle from the documentation but the lower triangle cluster looks REALLY similar.

**My question, why are all the clusters different? Which one is correct?**

This is the documentation for the input distance matrix for `linkage`

```
y : ndarray
A condensed or redundant distance matrix. A condensed distance matrix is a flat array containing the upper triangular of the distance matrix.
```

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

%matplotlib inline

#Test Data
DF_sim = DF_c93tom.iloc[:10,:10] #Similarity Matrix
DF_sim.columns = DF_sim.index = range(10) 
#print(DF_test)
#           0  1         2         3  4  5  6  7  8  9
# 0  1.000000  0  0.395833  0.083333  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 1  0.000000  1  0.000000  0.000000  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 2  0.395833  0  1.000000  0.883792  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 3  0.083333  0  0.883792  1.000000  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 4  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  1  0  0  0  0  0
# 5  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  0  1  0  0  0  0
# 6  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  0  0  1  0  0  0
# 7  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  0  0  0  1  0  0
# 8  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  0  0  0  0  1  0
# 9  0.000000  0  0.000000  0.000000  0  0  0  0  0  1

#Dissimilarity Matrix
DF_dissm = 1 - DF_sim

#Redundant Matrix
#np.tril(DF_dissm).T == np.triu(DF_dissm)
#True for all values

#Hierarchical Clustering for square and triangle matrices
fig_1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.title("Square")
Z_square = linkage((DF_dissm.values),method="average")
dendrogram(Z_square)

fig_2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.title("Triangle Upper")
Z_triu = linkage(np.triu(DF_dissm.values),method="average")
dendrogram(Z_triu)

fig_3 = plt.figure(3)
plt.title("Triangle Lower")
Z_tril = linkage(np.tril(DF_dissm.values),method="average")
dendrogram(Z_tril)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a 2D array is passed as the first argument to scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage,
it is treated as a sequence of observations, and [`scipy.spatial.pdist` is used](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L652) to convert it to a squence of pairwise distances between observations.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2614) regarding this behavior since it means that passing a "distance matrix" such as `DF_dissm.values` (silently) produces an **incorrect result**.

So [the upshot of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18952587/190597) is that none of these

```
Z_square = linkage((DF_dissm.values),method="average")
Z_triu = linkage(np.triu(DF_dissm.values),method="average")
Z_tril = linkage(np.tril(DF_dissm.values),method="average")
```

produce the desired result. **Instead use**

- [`np.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

  ```
  h, w = arr.shape
  Z = linkage(arr[np.triu_indices(h, 1)], method="average")
  ```
- or [`spatial.distance.squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html):

  ```
  from scipy.spatial import distance as ssd
  Z = linkage(ssd.squareform(arr), method="average")
  ```
- or apply [`spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to the original points:

  ```
  Z = hierarchy.linkage(ssd.pdist(points), method="average")
  ```
- or pass the 2D array `points`:

  ```
  Z = hierarchy.linkage(points, method="average")
  ```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy as hier
from scipy.spatial import distance as ssd
np.random.seed(2016)

points = np.random.random((10, 2))
arr = ssd.cdist(points, points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4)

ax[0].set_title("condensed upper triangular")
Z = hier.linkage(arr[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], 1)], method="average")
hier.dendrogram(Z, ax=ax[0])

ax[1].set_title("squareform")
Z = hier.linkage(ssd.squareform(arr), method="average")
hier.dendrogram(Z, ax=ax[1])

ax[2].set_title("pdist")
Z = hier.linkage(ssd.pdist(points), method="average")
hier.dendrogram(Z, ax=ax[2])

ax[3].set_title("sequence of observations")
Z = hier.linkage(points, method="average")
hier.dendrogram(Z, ax=ax[3])

plt.show()
```

[image]