# What should be the input of the linkage function in scipy?

Tags: python, matrix, cluster-analysis

I computed the similarity between malware files using Bindiff, accordingly built a similarity matrix based on the pairwise similarity comparison. I want to cluster the results using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(y, method='single', metric='euclidean')`, but the documentation says that y should be A condensed or redundant distance matrix. 
So, how can I convert the similarity matrix (NOT distance matrix) to the required format?

Where on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952587/use-distance-matrix-in-scipy-cluster-hierarchy-linkage) it's mention `y` can be he upper triangle of the distance matrix. But I want to point out that the order of comparison in Bindiff changes the result so `similarity(file1,file2) != similarity(file2,file1)`

so how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just implement hierarchical clustering yourself!

There are [tutorials for implementing it](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/hierarchical_clustering). All you need to do is use a similarity rather than a distance.

But as you will quickly realize, you *need* to make it a symmetric similarity, min, average, max of the two distance, whatever.

Comment: But the similarity matrix that I have isn't symmetric, as stated in my post, this is due to the computation of bindiff is affected by the order of the files

Comment: Yes, again: you *need* to make it symmetric with one of aforementioned functions, for example. Otherwise, you cannot cluster. Consider two points, but with bindiff 1 resp. 2 - at which similarity do they merge? Choose one answer.