# How to draw a dendrogram from a NetworkX minimum spanning tree?

Tags: python, scipy, networkx

I've computed a minimum spanning tree from a distance matrix, using NetworkX. I want now to build a dendrogram from it.

My MST :
[image: ![MST](http://www.bedside-ai.com/mst.png)]

I've tried using the adjacency matrix (using NetworkX's to_pandas_adjacency)

(T is my MST)

```py
df = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(T)

from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
dist_array = squareform(df) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952587/use-distance-matrix-in-scipy-cluster-hierarchy-linkage

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
mergings = linkage(dist_array, method='complete', metric='euclidean')
dendrogram(mergings, labels = distances.index, leaf_rotation=90, leaf_font_size=14)
plt.show()
```

Now, as the adjacency matrix is filled with 0's for non-edges, I guess linkage compute Euclidean distance and end up with a 3 clusters dendrogram (where all the cluster's points are at 0 distance), while I'm expecting to get the same linkage as in my original MST !

[image]

I tried using inf or large value for the nonedge default value to to_pandas_adjacency, but end up with invalid matrix...

Help anyone ? My best guess is that I'm not understanding and using linkage as I should...

**Edit**
I know, doing it the other way around (DT and then build the MST) might probably be easier, but I need to reproduce the order of operations in order to recreate the results of an original study...

**Edit 2**
Since the scipy's linkage function compute Euclidean distance between each point (or node here), I guess (but without any certainty) I need to find a way to convert my adjacency matrix to an array similar to what's linkage function output, ie weighted edge list, but with sub clusters size as fourth column.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but your graph contains a cycle, so it is not a tree.

Comment: I'm using built-in netwokx's MST function (T=nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)), but I notice weird drawing troubles (nodes are, I think, just drawn on top of edges, but without being connected to it), but those aren't cycles in adjacency matrix though (42's only edge is to 40).

Comment: Yeah, that is expected as there is no edge avoidance in `networkx`s node layout routines.

Comment: Can you link to the edge list of your MST?

Comment: @Paul Brodersen Sure ! 
Here is the weighted edges list : https://www.bedside-ai.com/edges_list
And the MST as a (binary) pickle : https://www.bedside-ai.com/mst_graph.pkl

Comment: A problem may be that your `dist_array` is just the adjacency matrix, not a distance matrix. I would assume that you would need to compute the path length between all combinations of nodes to populate a distance matrix (`nx.shortest_path_length`).

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but I'm not quite sure : I do have my original distance matrix (from which my graph and MST are computed), so I don't need to compute it again, but, as clustering is actually my main end goal, how can I be sure that I don't end up with different clusters (following Kruskal's for the MST (I know, even there, I can have multiple MST for a single graph) and minimization of Euclidean distances for linkage/DT - there is a glimpse in my code, should be ```method="single"```) ? Thanks for the help;)

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar question and am trying to find a solution. It's the first time I've posted an answer, so please let me know if there is any issue.

I suggest you use `linkage` and `dendrogram` directly from `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` rather than using the networkx package.

You first convert the distance matrix to a condensed distance matrix by `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` and then you use `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` to obtain the clustering.

There are different distance functions you can use in `linkage`

Finally you plot the clustering using `dendrogram`.

The results shall be consistent with the minimum spanning tree in networkx.

Comment: i used the floyd_warshall_numpy function in networkx to generate my distance matrix. i was actually interested in generating a dendrogram that match an ontology (DAG), so i took a small square from the total result of the FWN function.